# normal closures and generating sets of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with $\ll g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_n\gg =G$($\ll a,\cdots ,b \gg $ means the normal closure of $\{a,\cdots ,b \}$ in $G $). Then, when can we establish $<g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_n>=G $? Surely, if $G $ is abelian, done. But what can we know on nonabelian cases? Are there some useful theorems?

If $G $ is nilpotent, then I have just realized that there is no proper contranormal subgroup of $G $, thus done. Can I generalize this to residually nilpotent groups?

Comment: What does $\langle\!\langle\rangle\!\rangle$ denote, the smallest normal subgroup containing $g_1, \ldots, g_n$?

Comment: Yes. It's the normal subgroup generated by all conjugates of $g_1,\cdots ,g_n $.

Comment: Okay, I just deleted an answer of mine where I mentioned that symmetric groups yield counterexamples to the claim. This probably isn’t of much interest to you (as symmetric groups are not residually nilpotent for $n ≥ 3$ as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free groups are residually nilpotent, and it is not true then.

For example for $F = \langle a,b \rangle$ free of rank $2$, $\langle ab^2,ba \rangle^F = F$, but $\langle ab^2,ba \rangle \ne F$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice counterexample!